# Validated and uploaded image incorrect name saved in MySQL in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, request, image-uploading

Validation of text and photo takes place in StorePost FormRequest.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'exerpt => 'required',
            'photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ];
    }
```

Then the controller part:

```
public function store( StorePost $request )
    {
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->photo->extension();  
        $request->photo->move(public_path('post-images'), $imageName);

        // may modify image name here but it's not elegant
        //$data = $request->all();
        //$data['photo'] = $imageName;

        Post::create( $request->all() );
    }
```

Image saves in MySQL as `/private/var/folders/zr/y1drl_rs0sl75rxvgkx8ntzm0000gn/T/phpUJKeEG`.
How can I set its name before the request gets to the controller?

I wouldn't like to do this such as here (commented lines).

Comment: I don't get the question. Setting the name before getting inside the controller's logic? I guess that you could set it up in your client side but I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$imageName = time().'_'.$request->photo->extension();  
$request->photo->storeAs('public/post-images',$imageName);

$post = new Post;
//...
$post->photo = $imageName;
//...
$post->save();
```